# Add Not Nullable column to laravel migration with existing DB data

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, laravel, laravel-4

I have to add a new column to an existing table that already has data in it and running into a bit of a hiccup.

1. How can I add this column? Its going to be a `Not Nullable` field. I'm ok with populating it with default data for right now and going back and updating later. so if we need to drop constraints while adding. *I'm assuming I'm going to need to utilize straight SQL queries.*
2. Make this work w/ PHPUnit and SQLite, currently I'm getting an error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL (SQL: alter table "tracks" add column "short_description" text not null)`

How would I modify this migration?

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('tracks', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->text('short_description')->after('description');
    });
}
```

Comment: you have to change your default value as well, just like the error says. You cannot have a `null` default value on a field which is `not null`. That's an outright contradiction.

Comment: what kinda throws me for a curve, is I already have a description column on the table thats the same as the short description.  `$table->text('description');` its created when the migration runs to create the table and seems to work just fine. :/  However, if I look at a description of the DB table in mysql I can clearly see it creates the column as NOT NULL, but with a NULL default value.

And I can't set a default value on a text column. Which is why I was thinking I would have to drop the constraints on the table while the column was being created, and push in a temp default.

Comment: found this snippet in another answer.

"when creating a table for the first time, it's fine to have some columns be not nullable, but when altering and adding a column, even though the table is empty, for some reason it balks."

Answer (score 4):

You have to set default value:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('tracks', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->text('short_description')->after('description')->default('default_value');
    });
}
```